# How to convert my array to a string in Bash?

Tags: arrays, string, bash

This is my Bash script that reads values from a temperature sensor and shows them in a line. I want to separate my array elements by a comma, like this example: `[1,2,3,5]`, then to replace a line that exists in another file by this string.

`temp.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0 ; 12 - $i ; i++))
  do
  x=$(cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000075292ed/w1_slave | grep "t=" | awk -F "t=" '{print $2/1000}')
  field[$i]=$x
  echo "${field[$i]}"
done | column
```

Comment: Is `column` doing anything here? Does the `echo` output more than one value on a given line? What does the output of this command look like exactly? What about if you don't use `column`?

Comment: Why are you sampling the same device each time through the loop?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm assuming to get temperatures multiple times and average the value or something similar. Although many of these sensors don't like being read over and over without sleeping inbetween.

Comment: Are you saying you want the values of `field` as a string? You can always do `mystr="${field[@]}"` for a space separated string of values. If you want to remove the spaces, then `tr -d ' ' <<<$mystr`.

Comment: @Etan Reisner column  gives me the opportunity to have the array elements horizontally  I am sampling the same device to see the change  of temperature and show them in  graph ( the file that I said I want to access is a html file that contains the graph)

Comment: Hah, I basically only ever use `column -t` so I'd forgotten that `column` works like `paste` in other cases.

Comment: @DavisC.Rankin look his is my result I want to have this result in a string instead of obtaining it in the terminal                       pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./temp.sh
[ 21.875 , 21.875 , 21.937 , 21.875 , 21.937 , 21.937 , 21.937 , 21.937 , 21.937 , 22 ,  21.937 , 21.937 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you I have found a solution

```
#!/bin/bash
f="myArray_a = ["
for ((i=0 ; 12 - $i ; i++))
  do
  x=$(cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000075292ed/w1_slave | grep "t=" | awk - F "t=" '{print $2/1000}')
  if [ $i -eq 11 ]
  then
  x=$(printf %.3f] $x)
  f="$f $x"
  echo "$f"
  else
  x=$(printf %.3f, $x)
  f="$f $x"
  fi



done | column
```

Answer (score 5):

So one way we could do this is to emulate the `join()` functionality provided by many languages:

```
function join()
{
    local IFS="$1"
    shift
    echo "$*"
}
```

Then we can call:

```
READINGS="[$(join "," "${field[@]})"]"
```

Here's an example:

```
$ MY_ARRAY=("one" "two" "three")
$ join "," "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"
one,two,three
```

This works by changing Bash's [Internal Field Separator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184867/78871). `$*` is the used for expanding all arguments using the `$IFS` as a separator.

We could also avoid the `join` function and just do it like this:

```
READINGS="[$(IFS=","; echo "${field[*]}")]"
```

Comment: when I tried it , it shows the same result as without IFS :  pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./temp.sh
21.437 21.437 21.437 21.437 21.437 21.437 21.437 21.437 21.5 21.5 21.5 21.5

Comment: If not, try posting your new code in an edit to the question and I'll take a look.